# Extending ext4 partition on running system

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, gparted, ext4

I need to add more space to ext4 partition by adding 5Gb unalocated space. How to manage this in following situation:

[image]

Currently system not allows me resize it:
[image]

Comment: There is no way to do it on a running system. You'd need to use a live USB, and also, you'd need to move the swap partition out of the way first.

Comment: And in order to move swap you need to right-click it and swapoff.